# HashSet doesn't decline second add call

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I have just started with Collection and I have written code to test with `HashSet`

Here is the code (Person.java):

```
public class Person
{
  int id;

  public Person(int id)
  {
    this.id=id;
  }

  public int getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id)
  {
    this.id=id;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o)
  {
    if (o instanceof Person)
    {
      Person p=(Person)o;
      if (this.id==p.id)
        return false;
      else
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
  }

  public int hashCode()
  {
    return 21*id;
  }
}
```

And the Implementation class, just a simple class:

```
import java.util.*;

class HashSetTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Set<Person> set=new HashSet<Person>();
    Person p1=new Person(6);
    Person p2=new Person(6);
    System.out.println(set.add(p1));
    System.out.println(set.add(p2));        
  }
}
```

If I am not wrong the second `System.out.println` statement should return `false` because it should not add the element as it is duplicate but it's returning true.

Answer (score 6):

It seems the `Person.equals` method is returning `false` when elements match.

It should be

```
if (this.id==p.id)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Comment: or just `return this.id == p.id;`

Comment: Thanks its work...Just a question might be a very dumb one when one does the call to equals and hashocde happens as i havent written no call to it

Comment: @Deepak_Sharma: Look at the source of `HashSet` and follow the control flow.

Answer (score 1):

Your `equals` method has a problem. It returns `false` when the id is the same.